# Find signal's maximum peak in window

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, signal-processing

I have a 9-dimensional signal (as a `csv` from [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/Seanny123/54a514dbee827d84841e5eb16cb06778)) that looks like this:
[image: signal_plot]

A signal peaks every 30 steps. I want to get the maximum values of the peaks in that 30 second window. Here's what I've hacked together so far, where `sig` is the signal loaded from the `csv` file and `max_res` is the desired result:

```
trial_num = 8
dims = 9
step = 30
max_res = np.zeros(trial_num)

tmp = sig.reshape((trial_num, step, dims))
max_dim = np.argmax(np.sum(tmp, axis=1), axis=1)

sing_dim = np.zeros((trial_num, step))
for t_i in range(trial_num):
    sing_dim[t_i] = tmp[t_i, :, max_dim[t_i]]

max_res = np.max(sing_dim, axis=1)
```

How can I replace the for-loop with a vectorized operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of getting the positions of the maximum value and then retrieving the values thanks to the positions, you can directly ask `numpy` to retrieve the maximum values:

```
tmp = sig.reshape((trial_num, step, dims))
max_res = np.max(np.max(tmp, axis=1), axis=1)
```

I suggest you, however, to use a function to encapsulate this behaviour. It could take the amount of steps per cycle as a parameter and compute the rest from there:

```
def max_peak_values(data, steps_per_cycle=30):
    length, dims = data.shape
    trials = length // steps_per_cycle
    new_shape = trials, steps_per_cycle, dims

    return np.max(np.max(data.reshape(new_shape), axis=1), axis=1)
```

and use it like:

```
max_res = max_peak_values(sig, 30)
```

Comment: For my benefit, could you explain in English what the result of the `np.max(tmp, axis=1)`? Can I think of it as something like "the peaks in each dimension across all trials"?

Comment: @Seanny123 Not sure of the proper terminology since English isn't my native language, but, as regard to the `reshape`, I’d say it's rather "the maximal value in each trial and each dimensions across all values for that trial and dimension" (not necessarily peak, as a negative peak will be the minimal value). This will give you an array of shape `trials, dims` (8, 9) in your case. Then, the second `np.max` will be "the peak for each trial across all dimensions" which is the value you are looking for.

Comment: @Seanny123 Note that this will only work if, for each trial, there is at least one peak with positive values. You may want to throw an `np.abs` somewhere if you want to take into account peaks with negative values.